# Multiple color matplotlib markers

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to create a timeline of events where some of the events are effected by other events in the timeline,

I want to use solid and multiple color markers so I could know which event was effected from other events,

so my timeline would have markers with different colors like -

blue, black, blue, blue-AND-black, orange, orange-AND-blue, orange-AND-blue-AND-black, black, blue

I'm using a function to select colors by value but only one color at a time, which is not useful for my case.

the function I'm using -

```
def SetColor(x):
    if(x <= 3):
        return "green"
    elif(x == 5):
        return "red"
    elif(x>=10):
        return "black"
```

my code until now -

```
fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Scatter(
    y = [0 for l in range(52)],
    x = time_line,
    text = label_fig,
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict(
        size = stages_fig,
        color = list(map(SetColor, stages_fig)),
        sizemode = 'area',
        sizeref = 2.*max([10])/(40.**2),
        sizemin = 1
    )
)])
fig.update_yaxes(title="POC", visible=True, showticklabels=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: This example from the [official docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html) shows markers in the form of little pie charts.

Comment: I've seen this example, but I'm not sure how to use it to define a function that according to my data creates solid and multiple color markers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which maps your value to a color like so:

```
def set_color(value):
    color_dict = {**{value: "green" for value in range(0,4)}, **{value: "green-red" for value in range(4,5)}, **{value: "red" for value in range(5,6)}, **{value: "red-black" for value in range(6,10)}} # can modify colors, values in color_dict
    return "black" if value >= 10 else color_dict.get(value, "white") # can put some other value than "white"
```

Comment: the problem is that "color-other_color" format is not a valid color input for matplotlib,
The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
  - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
  - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
  - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
  - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
  - A named CSS color:
        aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
        beige, bisque, black...
  - A number that will be interpreted as a color
    according to scatter.marker.colorscale
  - A list or array of any of the above